# Kendo ui Slider with relative width

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui

does anyone know how set the width of a kendo ui slider?
Preferably a would set a relative width.

The only way I found is this, and it is fixed width only:

```
<input id="slider" class="balSlider" style="width:100px;" />
```

Or is there a Javascript option or something, so that I can use the resize function?

Thanks

Comment: or its just impossible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,
this seems to work quite well:

```
<input id="slider" type="range" style="width:100%;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS

```
.k-slider-horizontal .k-slider-buttons .k-slider-track
{
width:250px !important;
}
```

Thanks
Ab

Comment: Sorry, for me this does not work. but thanks for your answer!